# God and the meaning of the term 'God'

Tags: theology

Can we move from the thought of God to a proof that there is a God ?

1 If God is possible or actual then he is contingent or necessary .

2 God is possible or actual .

3 God is contingent or necessary .

4 God is not contingent .

5 God is necessary .

6 If God is necessary then he is actual .

C God is actual .

Comment: What is the difference with [your previous post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72616/can-we-prove-that-god-exists-from-the-concept-god) ?

Comment: The difference is that God is both possible and actual .

Comment: For the "argument" 5-6-C is enough: it is a "theorem" of modal logic that is something is *necessary*, then it is *actual*.

Comment: Bot a "valid" argument proves the conclusion only if its premises are true: on what ground we can assert that God is necessary ?

Comment: That's a very good point . We could invoke the concept of metaphysical necessity . Such a truth is true both in this actual world and all possible worlds .

Comment: Premise 1 seems pretty flawed here.  If God were possible, how would that lead to him being contingent or necessary?  It seems like perhaps that is smuggled into your particular definition of God; but it doesn't seem to follow just based off what is here.  I don't see how the _possibility_ of something can lead to it being contingent or necessary on it's own.

Comment: There is no way to deduce the existence of an object from the meaning of a term "naming" that object.

Comment: What do you mean by 'God'?

Comment: Peter's onto something here. We can counterpose - "God" doesn't seem to even make sense as a possibility, and I would contend that there is no real "thought about God". Per Wittgenstein, whereof we cannot speak, thereof we must be silent.

Comment: Are you reinventing the ontological argument?

Comment: God's existence does not have to be determined through the application of any principles of formal logic. There is a 'natural' logical process which as a natural function of the human mind, precedes the analytical human 'creation' which is formal logic. Spinoza simplified the entire process with this argument; 'If anything exists, then God exists". You have to work your way through this, which is not easy or just google it and see what commentators say about Spinoza's argument. It is not simple-minded, or easy to dismiss, although it may appear that way. CMS

Answer (score -3):

Yes absolutely, it's just that many atheists are confused with what the term "G-d" means, they would attribute it to some kind of object or property that we can observe in the world, and therefore have questions and assumptions that would contradict many points made here.

But yes if G-d is defined as that which caused all else to come into existence, then all that would need to be proven is that everything must have a first cause.

In order to prove that, it would be necessary to explain how everything works by way of cause and effect, but if it were to have always worked that way, then there would be no end.

In other words it would need to be shown that the universe is finite, to the extent that it must have a beginning, or an "original cause", and once that has been established, then our definition of "G-d" is reached.

The only problem is atheists making assumptions, based on other contexts, to think "g-d" is some kind of finite existence or even "person" [chas veshalom], so the first step is to remove all previous assumptions and only deal with the information given in the current context, then we can move on to the actual logical proofs.

Comment: - "... the proof that there's a God?"
- "Yes, absolutely."

Comment: @Robert are you trying to make some kind of counter argument